# Сканер штрих кодов + веб приложение

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть система автоматизации для аптек написанный на PHP mysql javascript и естественно HTML (вообщем браузерная). Нужны советы или идеи насчет интеграции со сканером штрих кодов. В базе есть почти все названия препаратов. Могу ли я просто подключить сканер штрих кода к компу и дальше использовать его как обычную клавиатуру. Может ли он ввести данные в любой инпут или есть какие то нюансы ?

Comment: Если драйвера клавиатуры стоят для сканетра то покатит если нет то нет то надо своё что то писать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сканеры штрих-кода обычно работают в двух вариантах: 
1) Эмуляция клавиатуры (те, кто подключаются через PS/2 или работают как USB HID)
2) Эмуляция COM-порта (те, которые подключаются к COM порту либо являются USB Serial Device)

Взаимодействие с первыми аналогично клавиатуре. Если во время работы устройства фокус на поле ввода, то ввод со сканера будет направлен в это поле.

Второй тип сканеров штрих-кода использует драйвер и записывает результат ввода в файл, куда именно - должно быть в описании устройства.

Если Вы хотите с минимальными затратами организовать «рабочее место оператора» с взаимодействием через веб, то вариант с USB HID — это ваш вариант. Вы просто с помощью PHP рисуете форму, с полем, куда JS-ом выставляете фокус. Оператор, «пикнув» сканнером штрихкода, просто введет туда цифры. (И не забываем, какой еще ОГРОМНЫЙ плюс возникает, если штрихкод потерт и не читается — оператор просто набивает артикул на клавиатуре в это поле.)

См. также https://toster.ru/q/10011 ; работа с СОМ-портом https://habrahabr.ru/post/240775/

Comment: Да спасибо ! как раз попробовал через такой сканер USB HID. и как вы говорили это наш вариант

Comment: Если подходит, то можно принять ответ, раз он отвечает на вопрос - это поможет впоследствии тем, кто ищет аналогичную информацию.